# ASP.NET Web Sites Examples

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

We plan to develop a ASP.NET ( VS 2010 ) web site.

We need to know if there are any ready made startup ASP.NET web sites so we can get them and adjust / upgrade according to our needs.

Thank you for your quick reponse
John.

Comment: If you're referring to a site template, I would just make one from scratch using Master Pages. If you read up on it, the process wont be too hard at all.

Comment: what kind of website are you looking to develop? Are you looking for a CMS solution? if so, there are plenty open source ones to choose from in the .NET world - http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/categories.aspx. I think you may need to be more specific in your question to get some decent answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of examples out there, and even VS 2010 has some templates that will get you started.  There isn't really much detail about what kind of website you are starting up, so beyond that you probably won't get much in the way of answers here to your question.  Most of the questions on here are of a more technical nature, and without showing that you are attempting something specific and that you have tried it on your own, answers will likely be few and far between.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I like your bio tag, but would recommend changing `do while(notPerfect == True)` to just `do while(notPerfect)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out some of the starter kits posted on asp.net:

http://www.asp.net/community/projects#jm_starter_kits_and_samples